# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBody' of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to teach myself to use Google Apps Script, but somehow every function I try returns this error immediately. And since I'm a huge beginner, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a simple example of a code I tried to run:

```
function myFunction(){
//application
//file
var ad = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var docBody = ad.getBody () ;
var paragraphs = docBody.getParagraphs();
//paragraphs[0]. setText ("MY NEW TEXT"):
//var attr = paragraphs[0].getAttributes() ;
//Logger.log(attr);
paragraphs[0].setAttributes({FONT_SIZE:40});
}
```

Yet no matter what I'm running really, I get this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBody' of null
> myFunction    @ Code.gs:5

What am I doing wrong?

I have an open Google Doc, I've allowed permissions to run the script project. What else should I try? Thanks.

Comment: Error means, that `ad` returns `null`, which means it won't access the document. Is your script container-bound, or stand-alone?

Comment: I don't know how to distinguish. I created it simply by choosing "Extensions > App Script" in the Google Doc.

Comment: if so it's container-bound. Container-bound means script is within the same document. I don't see any reasons why you couldn't access the document to retrieve body, if you authorized the script.

Comment: Oh boy, somehow my adblocker was interfering. Disregard!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get [`getActiveDocument()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getactivedocument) working you need to use it in a script that [is container-bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_containers):

1. Create a new Google Document
2. Go to `Extensions > Apps Script`
3. Run your function inside of it.

If your script is not `container-bound`, you need to use the [`openById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openById(String)) or [`openByUrl(url)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openByUrl(String)) methods, in order to retrieve a [`Document`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document)

Comment: Those steps are exactly what I did, sadly. 
 Ideally I'd like the script to work on any Google Doc of mine, so I'd rather not make it stuck to a certain Doc URL.

Comment: Never mind. It was Adblock issue.

Comment: Please, consider upvoting this answer for another members of the community

Answer (score 1):

Adblock software was preventing the running somehow. Disabled it and runs fine now. Disregard!